# How am I able to use my android phone as bluetooth headset?

Tags: android, bluetooth, low-level, headset

I know, there are some apps, which are maybe able to do that, but i also know, there is a way, in which i have to change some code to add the a2dp, avrcp and the hfp protocol(?) to my bluetooth module. unfortunatelly i can't find a good tutorial for that.. can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement A2DP sink or HFP, you may porting the code from google android source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/master/src/com/android/bluetooth